# Windows Exploit Protection: what is SEHOP setting: "TelemetryOnly" for?

Tags: windows

I'm reading into the different exploit protection methods from Microsoft. One is SEHOP, if I check it e.g. with PS:

`Get-ProcessMitigation -System`

I get:

```
...
SEHOP:
    Enable                             : NOTSET
    TelemetryOnly                      : OFF
    Audit                              : NOTSET
    Override SEHOP                     : False
...
```

What is "TelemetryOnly"?
Internet search was not successful so far.

Answer (score 1):

The ProcessMitigation docs page says:

> The ProcessMitigations module (also known as the Process Mitigation Management Tool) provides functionalities to allow users to configure and audit exploit mitigations for increased process security or for converting existing Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit (EMET) policy settings.

Looking in the EMET user guide, there is a mention of

> Configuring Local Telemetry
> For troubleshooting purposes, we have added a “Local Telemetry” mode. When this mode is enabled, the
> information that would be sent through the “Early Warning” will be saved locally instead in a user-defined
> folder. To enable this mode, users need to create two entries in the registry hive
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EMET:
> LocalTelemetryPath (string): path where to save the information (i.e. c:\emet_local_telemetry)
> Optionally, you can create the following registry key to control what kind of MiniDump file to create:
> MiniDumpFlags (DWORD): 0x1ff (default value)
> More information on the possible flags are available at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms680519(v=vs.85).aspx) article.

You can view the user guide [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/1/771312BF-53F1-4FE1-B894-8EE93ABE567E/EMET%205%205%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf).

So in essence, it's a way to enable or disable the Early Warning Program system.

Comment: Then I guess we need to wait for Microsoft to update their documentation in the context of SEHOP...

Comment: yes, or there might be someone who dug into this an knows more? since I'm new on StackExchange, the original question has been posted on the security forum, but someone moved it to superuser, with the reasoning that this is about win telemetry and not SEHOP. but actually this is about SEHOP, since the option appears with the SEHOP settings... what "telemetry" in context of SEHOP are we talking about, why is it needed, where does the telemetry data go, to the MS cloud or local - I think these are legit security related questions...